# Show that the map $x \to \zeta_x$ is an isometric embedding of $\ell^1$ into $X'$

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces

Let $S$ be an infinite set and let $\lbrace s_n \rbrace_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of distinct points in $S$. Let $X$ be a Banach space of bounded functions on $S$, supplied with thr supremum norm.

If $x=(x_1, x_2,...) \in \ell^1$, then the definition $\zeta_x (f)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n f(s_n)$ yields a bounded linear functional on $X$.

Show that the map $x \to \zeta_x$ is an isometric embedding of $\ell^1$ into $X'$.

I have shown that $\zeta_x (f)$ is a bounded linear functional, how about the map above? how to show it is an isometric embedding?

Comment: Do you actually mean just that $X$ is _a_ Banach space of bounded functions on $S$, or is $X$ actually _the_ Banach space of bounded functions on $S$ (meaning the space of all bounded functions)? Not to be picky about English, but it makes a big difference here.

Comment: $X$ is a banach space of bounded functions on $S$

Comment: It is what the exercise say

Comment: I can't believe you've written exactly what the exercise says. For example, surely it says "Let $X$ be a Banach space of...", not "a Banach of...", right? It's not clear to me that you understand the issue here - does it actually say "a Banach space", not "the Banaach space"?

Comment: Or: Does the exercise actually say "poin" instead of "points"? (My point in pointing out these typos that don't matter is they make me think there may be another typo, which _does_ matter...)

Comment: Or, come to think of it, it might say something like "a Banach space consisting of the bounded functions on $S$" - that again would mean something totally different from what you wrote. You should probably show us the statement of the question, using _exactly_ the same words.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited it

Answer (score 0):

Although I still have my doubts regarding what was actually intended, the OP seems to have confirmed that he meant the question exactly as stated.

In that case this is trivially *false*. For example, let $X$ be the space of *constant* functions on $S$. If $x\in\ell^1$, $x\ne0$ but $\sum x_j=0$ then $\zeta_x=0$.